# We need to explain our tags

Tags: discussion, tags

We are starting to have a serious problem with tags. People are just tagging questions for the sake of tagging the question instead of thinking what the tag means.

I think this problem comes down to lack of explanation on the tags, by this I mean the tag descriptions and the wikis I know I have made a post previously asking people to start to bulk out the tags but now it is getting a bit more serious.

If we don't start to bulk out the tags questions are just going to get lost and people wont be able to get the answers they need, I know we are only a small site at the moment but we have the potential to grow and I would love that to happen.

So I would really like people to start editing tag wikis and if they don't fully understand what a tag should be focused on make a meta post ask people what the tag should be used for. I know we have a good community here and I think that we can really get this site to graduation in a reasonable amount of time.

So lets all go and make our tags more understandable and give them a bit more meaning.

Comment: I agree - though I am probably guilty myself.  This site needs to really get some newbies coming in and everyone else reading, asking and answering.  Anything that helps is a great idea.

Comment: Hi, having some problems in understanding how to pad out the tags - please can you give me some guidance.

Comment: @dougal3.0.0 sure thing, this basically means on a tag there is a section that says improve this tag and there you will be able to add information about that tag what we need in these are things like what the tag is about how to use it and even things like example questions

Comment: ♦. OK I may be being a bit of dumbo .  I have just posted a question but no where, when I went to put the tags in was there a place for me to do all of this.  I went to put in a new tag and still no explanation.  so I stuck to traditional ones.  I use firefox on a linux system - could this be an issue?  HEEEELP PLEEEASE!  I really want to do the right thing here!

Comment: @dougal3.0.0 this discussion is all centered around the description for a tag so if you click on any tag there will be a box with a tag description above a list of questions that have this tag inside that box there is a link to improve this tag info click on that it takes toy to a section to improve the description of the tag as this exchange is in beta still anybody can create new tags so some times we get too many tags that don't have any information of guide how to use them update this information helps people to use the tags correctly

Comment: ♦.  thanks I will take a look later.  Hope that I didn't cause too much grief with my tag!